# Task Scheduler Does Not Start Bat File

Tags: java, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

My bat file is:

```
 @echo off 
 java -cp * MyTimerTasker
```

I try to run main function in MyTimerTaskerClass. 
All jars and bat file are in same folder.
When I try to run bat file with double click, it runs.
When I try to run with right click and run as administrator, command window shows and disappears but my main function does not start.
When I try to run with task scheduler, it never starts.

Edit: My main class.

```
 public class MyTimerTasker {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FTPDownloadFiles ftpDownloadFiles = new FTPDownloadFiles();
    System.out.println("Running ...");
    DatabaseTask databaseTask = new DatabaseTask();
    databaseTask.connectToDatabase();
    ftpDownloadFiles.downloadFiles();

    try {
        databaseTask.parseFiles(JdbcConnection.filesPath);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    finally {
        try {
            databaseTask.closeConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Could you please include the main class source?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the classpath of all the files in the working directory. You should add the name of the jar to the classpath.

Comment: Could you get the output of the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

If you start as administrator, it starts in another directory (same if you start as a scheduled task).
You will have to set your working directory in the batchfile:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

This will change the working directory to the folder, where your batchfile resides.